# filtrar objeto por array javascript

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
alunos : { nome: 'teste',
           idade: '15',
           turma: 'turma 1'},
          { nome: 'teste2',
           idade: '16',
           turma: 'turma 2'},
          { nome: 'teste3',
           idade: '12',
           turma: 'turma 2'},
          { nome: 'teste3',
           idade: '14',
           turma: 'turma 4'},
          { nome: 'teste6',
           idade: '13',
           turma: 'turma 4'},
```

Preciso criar um novo array onde alunos.turma seja igual a ['turma 1', 'turma2'], tentei usar o filter mas não consegui.

Comment: Você quer modificar o atributo turma, String para Array?

Comment: Não quero filtrar o array onde o atributo turma seja igual a 'turma 1, ou 'turma 2'

Comment: Você vai passar um array como filtro, e quer obter um objeto?

Comment: Alunos é um objeto? Poderia melhorar esse Json acima, está confuso.

Comment: desculpe, alunos é um array de objetos, digitei incorretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não precise de tudo isso para resolver o problema, pelo que entendi só é preciso filtrar as turmas 1 e 2, sendo assim, um simples one-liner resolve:

```
alunos.filter(function(item){ return (['turma 1', 'turma 2'].indexOf(item.turma) !== -1); });
```

Que retorna um array com as 3 turmas encontradas:

```
[{nome: "teste", idade: "15", turma: "turma 1"},
{nome: "teste2", idade: "16", turma: "turma 2"},
{nome: "teste3", idade: "12", turma: "turma 2"}]
```

Utilizei o filter pelo fato de que o op disse `"tentei usar filter mas não consegui"` logo assume-se que gostaria de utiliza-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Basta percorrer com for e fazer a verificação

```js
let alunos = [ { nome: 'teste',
           idade: '15',
           turma: 'turma 1'},
          { nome: 'teste2',
           idade: '16',
           turma: 'turma 2'},
          { nome: 'teste3',
           idade: '12',
           turma: 'turma 2'},
          { nome: 'teste3',
           idade: '14',
           turma: 'turma 4'},
          { nome: 'teste6',
           idade: '13',
           turma: 'turma 4'} ];
           
let resul = [];
           
for(val in alunos)
  if(alunos[val]['turma'] === "turma 1" || alunos[val]['turma'] === "turma 2")
    resul.push(alunos[val]);

console.log(resul);
```

Comment: certo, o valor de alunos[val]['turma']  está fixo sendo passado 'turma 1' ou 'turma 2', porém se for uma variavel array turmafiltro = ['turma 1', 'turma 2]], teria que fazer um for nesse array?

Answer (score 1):

Montei um exemplo para você utilizando a função [*filter*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

```
var alunos = [{ nome: 'teste',
               idade: '15',
               turma: 'turma 1'},
              { nome: 'teste2',
               idade: '16',
               turma: 'turma 2'},
              { nome: 'teste3',
               idade: '12',
               turma: 'turma 2'},
              { nome: 'teste3',
               idade: '14',
               turma: 'turma 4'},
              { nome: 'teste6',
               idade: '13',
               turma: 'turma 4'}];

var turmafiltro = ['turma 1', 'turma 2'];

function checkTurma(turma) {    
    if (turmafiltro.indexOf(turma.turma) >= 0)
    return true;
}

var result = alunos.filter(checkTurma);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: certo o valor da turma.turma está fixo sendo passado 'turma 1' ou 'turma 2', porém se for uma variavel array turmafiltro = ['turma 1', 'turma 2]], teria que fazer um for nesse array?

Comment: Ai você usa o indexOf

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma possível é usar filter e some;

```js
var alunos = [{
  nome: 'teste',
  idade: '15',
  turma: 'turma 1'
 },
 {
  nome: 'teste2',
  idade: '16',
  turma: 'turma 2'
 },
 {
  nome: 'teste3',
  idade: '12',
  turma: 'turma 2'
 },
 {
  nome: 'teste3',
  idade: '14',
  turma: 'turma 4'
 },
 {
  nome: 'teste6',
  idade: '13',
  turma: 'turma 4'
 }
]
var turmas = ['turma 1', 'turma 2'];

var filtrados = alunos.filter(function(a) {
 return turmas.some(function(t) {
  return a.turma === t;
 })
})

console.log(filtrados)
```